# Low power, large weight sensor needed

Tags: electrical-engineering, sensors

I am looking for a weight sensor which has a range from 2000 kg to 30000 kg to measure the weight of passing trucks. 
Accuracy is not very important. Power use is very important, typically 3.3v.

Do there exist these kind of sensors?

Comment: why not use a lever and measure a fraction of the actual weight?

Comment: This seems like a product recommendation question, which is not [on-topic](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for this site.

Comment: Power is measured in watts (W), not in volts (V).

Answer (score 1):

You can look at this product, which is rated up to 100 T and has a calibration certificate [F317](http://www.novatechloadcells.co.uk/ds/f317.htm)

Made by Novatech : http://www.novatechloadcells.co.uk/ds/f317.htm